# JS/Jquery Replace inner text without destroy event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is the html:

```
<div id="div001">
  This is ${Row.1}.
  <p>${Row.2} explain something else.</p>
  <p>${Row.3} welcome you. <span>${Hello.World}, this is a new world.</span></p>
</div>
```

What I want to do is replace the `${Row.1}` to the text `Row 1` without replacing entire `div001` DIV. Because this will destroyed the event on the `<p>` & `<span>`.

I currently able to achieve loop through all element and find the child node(without html tag in there), in this case is the first `<p>` & `<span>`, and replace the word with JQUERY `$(ele).text()`.

But i still can't find a way replace the ${Row.1} & ${Row.3}.

Please advise me, thank you.

Comment: do you also want to replace `${Hello.World}` with `"Hello World"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a recursive function that iterates through all child nodes, and if they're text nodes, replaces their text - if they're element nodes, recursively call the function on them:

```js
function replaceTextNodes(elm) {
  elm.childNodes.forEach((node) => {
    if (node.nodeType === 3) {
      // Text node:
      node.textContent = node.textContent.replace(/\${([^}]+)}/g, '$1');
    } else if (node.nodeType === 1) {
      // Element node, recurse:
      replaceTextNodes(node);
    }
  });
}
replaceTextNodes(document.querySelector('#div001'));
```

```html
<div id="div001">
  This is ${Row.1}.
  <p>${Row.2} explain something else.</p>
  <p>${Row.3} welcome you. <span>${Hello.World}, this is a new world.</span></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way that I can think of would be to wrap it in a `<span>`. Then you could target it with `$('#div001 > span')`:

```js
$('#div001 > span').text('Replaced');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="div001">
  <span>This is ${Row.1}.</span>
  <p>${Row.2} explain something else.</p>
  <p>${Row.3} welcome you. <span>${Hello.World}, this is a new world.</span></p>
</div>
```

If you explicitly want to replace the `${Row.x}` components, you can wrap those parts in `<span>` tags with an associated ID / class, and use that to target them:

```js
$('#one, #three').text('Replaced');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="div001">
  This is <span id="one">${Row.1}</span>.
  <p><span id="two">${Row.2}</span> explain something else.</p>
  <p><span id="three">${Row.3}</span> welcome you. <span>${Hello.World}, this is a new world.</span></p>
</div>
```

---

If you cannot change the HTML, your best bet would be to make use of a regex.

The following regex will replace anything in the format `${...}`:

```js
var element = document.getElementById('div001');
var result = element.innerHTML.replace(/\${\S+}/gm, "REPLACED");
element.innerHTML = result;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="div001">
  This is ${Row.1}.
  <p>${Row.2} explain something else.</p>
  <p>${Row.3} welcome you. <span>${Hello.World}, this is a new world.</span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: It came into my mind as well, but the new function in intended for an existing website, not likely possible to ask them to review all html and wrap it with a new html tag :(

Comment: You could use a regex without needing to update the HTML. I've updated my answer to showcase this.

Comment: whenever you replaced the innerHTML, it will destroy the event. You put this before your JS code then you will see it won't work when click on the Row.2: `document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].addEventListener("click",function(){console.log("clicked")})`